# "Starting April 2020, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later"

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to upload an app to the appstore and I'm getting this error:

> SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 12.1 SDK. Starting
>   April 2020, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with
>   the iOS 13 SDK or later, included in Xcode 11 or later.

I have this:

- **Hardware**: MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)
- **OS**: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G10021)     -- This is the max version I can get due to my hardware
- **Xcode**: 10.1 (10B61)   -- This is the max version I can get due to my OS. 11 is incompatible

What are my possible solutions?

I could buy a new Macbook but I'd rather do this as my last choice (too expensive!!)

I also downloaded this: https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/13.0.zip and unzipped here: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform`

It didn't work... it doesn't show as an option in Xcode Deployment Target:

[image: Deployment target in Xcode]

Comment: I do wish people would stop asking this. Your choice is: get a machine that can accept Catalina; or, never submit an app to the App Store again. Now choose!

Comment: You need a newer computer. It doesn't need to be brand new, even a 2015 MacBook can run Catalina.

Comment: The only solution is to get your app reviewed and submitted before March 31st.

Comment: thanks god I didn't listen to @matt. At the end, my hardware was capable of installing `Catalina` as I will put in an answer right now

Comment: I didn't say you needed a newer computer. Someone else said that. I said you needed a machine that can accept Catalina, if you want to submit apps going forward. You have one, you're fine for another year! Excellent.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up installing Catalina directly from the appstore.

I thought it wasnt supported but it is, as shown below:

[image: Catalina]